Efficiently solving linear systems of the form $A^T D A x = y$
Say I'm given an $m$ by $n$ matrix $A$ of rank $n$ and can spend as much time as I want precomputing on $A$. Then, I am given a diagonal $m$ by $m$ matrix $D$ and $n$-dimensional vector $y$ and have to solve for $x$ in $A^T D A x = y$. Assuming $m = O(n)$, how efficiently can this be done?
Note that if $m=n$ then you can precompute the inverse of $A$ and find $x = A^{-1} D^{-1} A^{-1^T} y$ which takes $O(n^2)$ time. However, I'm not sure how to do better than $O(n^3)$ for $m > n$.
